# AWS Cloudformation : ECS Task definition ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created cfn template to trigger cloudwatch event periodically to run an ecs task with Fargate launch type.
The CW rule looks like below:

```
sfECSScheduleEventRule:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Description: ''
Properties:
  State: ENABLED
  ScheduleExpression: rate(1 minute)
  Name: !Sub sf-eventrule-ecs-${WPRegion}-${WPEnv}
  Targets:
  - Id: !Sub sf-ecs-target-task-${WPRegion}-${WPEnv}
    Arn: !GetAtt
      - ECSCluster
      - Arn
    RoleArn: !GetAtt
      - ECSTaskExecutionRole
      - Arn
    EcsParameters:
      #arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:448965722616:task-definition/fargate-task-jp-stg:latest
      TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref sfECSTaskDefinition          
      TaskCount: !Ref ECSTaskDesiredCount
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      PlatformVersion: 'LATEST'
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsVpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          Subnets:
          - !Ref sfPrivateSubnet1
```

When I create the stack, I find the rule's target is like below:
[image]

Which fails to trigger the task. But when I change task revision from 4 to Latest **manually**, then it works. Task executes periodically.

[image]

How I can change the rule So that it points to the latest?

Comment: I dont know what else might be the problem?

Comment: Any reason why you create CW event rule, instead of using [ECS scheduling tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html) functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

```
TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref sfECSTaskDefinition
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition-return-values) this returns arn with the revision number. Also according to [TaskDefinitionArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-ecsparameters.html#cfn-events-rule-ecsparameters-taskdefinitionarn):

> If no task revision is supplied, it defaults to the most recent revision at the time of resource creation.

Thus I think if you manually create the arn, you should be able to get the most recent revision.

```
!Sub "arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:task-definition/fargate-task-jp-stg"
```

Don't know if your task family name `fargate-task-jp-stg` is parameterized or not in the template. If yes, then you can also reference it in the `Sub` intrinsic function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The manual arn works. BTW not AWS::Account-Id but AWS::AccountId

Comment: The documentation has changed, and no longer states that the most recent revision will be used. Any idea if this still works?